# How to display saved data by clicking view button

Tags: reactjs

I'm using fire base in back end and React js and Flux in front end. I have created a list of centers. Where user can login and they can hit the center menu, where they will get some fields and they can add center. And then I have created a list where they can view the list of center. In that list I have kept a button as "VIEW" by clicking that the user can view that particular record. I want that to be opened in Modal or Popup. I have tried importing Popup and Modal but I couldn't make it. Any one can guide me how to achieve that. Thanks in advance.

Below is the code where I have wrote to "ADD", "VIEW", "DELETE"

```
    class AddCenters extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {centers: []};
        this.props = props;


    }
    componentDidMount() {

      const db = firebase.firestore();
      const userRef = db.collection("center");

      let centers = [];

      userRef.get().then(doc => {
    //here I'm pushing the bind values
        doc.docs.forEach(d => {
          let center = d.data();
          center.id = d.id;
          centers.push(center)
        })

        this.setState({centers: centers})
      })

    }

    viewCenter = (id) => {
      //here is the code for view center where I consoled. I want this data to be displayed in popup or modal while clicking the button. 
      console.log('im view----->',id);
      let centers = [...this.state.centers];
      console.log('im centsers--->', centers);

    }


    deleteCenter = (id, index) => {
//this is the code for delete the value from list 
      console.log(id, index);
      let centers = [...this.state.centers];

      console.log(centers);
      firebase.firestore().collection('center').doc(id).delete().then(() => {
        console.log("Document successfully deleted!");

        centers.splice(index, 1);

        this.setState({centers: centers});
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
      });
    }



        render () {
          const item = {
            title: "Centers",
            to: "/add-center"
          };
          return (
            <Container fluid className="main-content-container px-4">
              {/* Page Header */}
              <Row noGutters className="page-header py-4">
                <PageTitle sm="4" title="Centers List" subtitle="List" className="text-sm-left" />
                <NavButton sm="4" item={item} className="text-sm-right"/>
              </Row>

              <Row>
                <Col>
                  <Card small className="mb-4">
                    <CardHeader className="border-bottom">
                      <h6 className="m-0">Active Users</h6>
                    </CardHeader>
                    <CardBody className="p-0 pb-3">
                      <table className="table mb-0">
                        <thead className="bg-light">
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="col" className="border-0">
                              #
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" className="border-0">
                              Center Name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" className="border-0">
                              Last Name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" className="border-0">
                              Medium
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" className="border-0">
                              Standard
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" className="border-0">
                              School
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" className="border-0">
                              View
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" className="border-0">
                              Delete

                            </th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                          {this.state.centers.map(( listValue, index ) => { //Here i'm binding  the value which will be added in list. 
                            return (
                              <tr key={index}>
                                <td>{index + 1}</td>
                                <td>{listValue.firstName}</td>
                                <td>{listValue.lastName}</td>
                                <td>{listValue.medium}</td>
                                <td>{listValue.standard}</td>
                                <td>{listValue.school}</td>
                                <td>
                                  <Button outline theme="accent" size="sm" onClick={this.viewCenter.bind(this, listValue.id, index)}>
                                      <i className="material-icons">visibility</i> View12345678
                                  </Button>
                                </td>
                                <td><Button outline theme="accent" size="sm" onClick={this.deleteCenter.bind(this, listValue.id, index)}>
                                      <i className="material-icons">delete</i> Delete
                                  </Button>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            );
                  })}
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </CardBody>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
              </Row>

            </Container>
          );

            }
          }
```

Comment: It would be nicer to read your code with comments.

Comment: Are you using a library for style? like material-ui or bootstrap? 
You can probably find in their docs many modal applications

Comment: @Misha no I'm not using any library.. Will try with that. Thanks for the info.